# What's the difference between "Discrete Fourier Series" and "Discrete Fourier Transform"?

Tags: dft

I look at the equations for DFS (Discrete Fourier Series) and DFT (Discrete Fourier transform) and the only difference I notice is that one has a **squiggle** above the letter and the other doesn't. The equations for x[n] and X[k] are exactly the same except for the presence or absence of a **squiggle**.

Example:

**DFS**:  $\tilde{x}[n]$ / $\tilde{X}[k]$

compared to:

**DTF**:  $x[n]$ / $X[k]$

What's the difference between "Discrete Fourier Series" and "Discrete Fourier Transform"?

Comment: I;m going to take a guess that DFS sequence $\tilde{x}[n]$ includes only the first N samples of sequence x[n], and they are repeated over and over ad infinitum... and the DFT is all the samples of  x[n] assuming  they are periodic with period N?? what's the difference?

Comment: @MrCausality Your guess is probably correct. Then the definitions coincide with DTFT (=Discrere time fourier transform) and DFT (=Discrete fourier transform), which are Fourier transform and series for discrete signals respectively.

Comment: The main difference between them is DFT=N.(DFS).

Comment: maybe with DFT you can have statistical variation in the periodic x[n] signal as long as it approaches the same periodic sequence as n approaches infinity... whereas DFS is exactly the same sequence without statistical variations??  I;m just taking a guess because the DFS/DFT description is from a deterministic DSP book...which is missing a little bit of the theory on statistical side...

Comment: a common statistical variation being additive gaussian white noise (AGWN) which averages itself out as n approaches infinity...

Answer (score 1):

They are the same thing. Just the same.

But for some reasons, we want to call the **first period** of the DFS sequences $\tilde{x}[n]$ and $\tilde{X}[k]$, as the new DFT sequences $x[n]$, $X[k]$.

They are both **periodic**. The periodicity of DFS is natural extension of periodicity of complex exponential and periodicity of time sequence, but the periodicity of DFT is **also forced** by the **modulus** operator.

Be careful! DFT is also linked with finite length aperiodic sequences $x[n]$ and their **DTFT** via the frequency sampling relation; i.e., $X[k] = X(e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N}k})$.

Because of this latter relation of the DFT $X[k]$ to the DTFT $X(e^{j \omega})$ of aperiodic (and finite length) sequences $x[n]$, in order to remember and imply the inherent periodicity in DFT (due to its definition through DFS) we shall enforce the **modulus** operator into the arguments of DFT sequences.